# Exposing/providing/injecting Activity to graph using dagger-android

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

When previously using Dagger 2.10, I had a pretty typical setup with an `ActivitySubcomponent` that had an `ActivityModule` which provided/exposed the `Activity` instance to the graph to be injected into other classes that required it.

With an `ActivityModule` like this:

```
@Module
public class ActivityModule {
    private final Activity activity;

    public ActivityModule(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    /**
     * Expose the activity to the graph.
     */
    @Provides @ActivityScope
    Activity activity() {
        return activity;
    }
}
```

Which would get the `Activity` instance by creating a new `ActivityModule` like this just before injecting:

```
    @Inject PermissionsHelper permissionsHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
            .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(getApplicationContext()))
            .plus(new ActivityModule(this))
            .inject(this);
    }
```

I could provide the `Activity` to something like this:

```
@ActivityScope
public class PermissionsHelper {

    private final Activity activity;

    @Inject
    PermissionsHelper(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }
}
```

---

However, after migrating to the new `dagger-android` setup (using [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp-dagger) as a guide), I no longer have easy access to the `Activity` instance without creating a separate module for each injected activity and then binding it's instance to an `Activity` object like so:

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBindingModule {

    @ActivityScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = arrayOf(SomeActivityModule::class))
    abstract fun someActivity(): SomeActivity
}
```

...

```
@Module
abstract class SomeActivityModule {

    /**
     * Expose the activity to the graph.
     */
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindActivity(someActivity: SomeActivity): Activity
}
```

While using the new `dagger-android` stuff, is there any way of avoiding that last step of creating a module, and binding it, for each Activity where I want its seed instance exposed to graph?

Comment: Having the same issue here. Did you figure out how to expose the activity?

Comment: @Ilber probably you've already figured that out but for future readers; as of now, there is no such annotation provided by Dagger to add `SomeActivity` directly to the graph. You can only use instance of `SomeActivity` inside modules included here `@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = arrayOf(SomeActivityModule::class))`